# Hiding comments from "Private group"

Tags: 7, comments

I am using the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) module. When I create a new group, and check off the "Private group" checkbox, the group will be private; so I am expecting that every comment will not be visible in Recent comment block.

Is it possible to ignore comments made inside a private group?

Comment: As side note, you are using an unregistered account that is recognized only from a single browser/computer. If you are using more than one browser, or computer, it is better you create an account.